# Lonesome Road DLC

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Can one visit the Long 15 & Dry Wells if :

1. Haven't started the Lonesome Road DLC
2. Didn't nuke both NCR & Legion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these locations aren't accessible until you've completed Lonesome Road. And you need to [nuke](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Apocalypse) the legion (for dry wells), the NCR (for the long 15), or both.